# How to only include result if all related values exist in input list

Tags: mysql, sql, query-builder

I've got an object `Product` that has many `Tag`s. I want to write a query that, given a list of `Tag` ids, only returns a `Product` if ALL the product's tags are included in the input list. The input list may have tag ids that are not part of a product, but that's OK, the product can still be returned (i.e. all of the product's tags must exist as a subset of the input list to be included in result).

I was able to write 1 query to accomplish this, but I'd really like to be able to do it without the sub-query in the JOIN. This is what I've got:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_tag ON product_tag.product_id = product.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product.id, COUNT(*) AS record_count
    FROM product
    LEFT JOIN product_tag ON product_tag.product_id = product.id
    GROUP BY product.id
) AS inner_q ON inner_q.id = product.id
WHERE product_tag.id in (1, 2, 3) -- Sample Tag ids
GROUP BY product.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = inner_q.record_count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[vkp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431869/vkp) led me in the right direction:

```
select * from product 
where id in 
(
 select product_id
 from product_tag 
 group by product_id
 having sum(case when id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) >= count(product_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you the required result?

```
select * from product 
where id in 
(select product_id
 from product_tag 
 group by product_id
 having sum(case when id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) >= 3)
```

Comment: Almost, but the >= 3 (presumably the count of the input list) makes it not work. If a product has only 2 tags (say, id 1 and 2) it would not be included when it should be

Comment: Your answer certainly got me on the right track, I just had to tweak it so the HAVING constraint was specifically the count of all tags a product has